# Cut holes using Box cutter results wired edge compared to Boolean tool

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am cutting holes using box cutter, while the ending result is different to understand.
[image]

You can see from this comparison, top is by using Box cutter, the bottom is using built-in boolean tool, the boolean results in good mesh while the Box cutter has wired mesh, I want to know:
1.which result is better?

2.whether the mesh produced by Box cutter should be avoid or not.

3.How to fix the mesh from Box cutter?

Comment: You can manually knife tool and dissolve to fix the box cutter result. But if boolean does what you need then why not stick with that?

Comment: Because boolean has more steps to go with, I have to create new object, add modifier, assign boolean object, move boolean object to position, with cutter, just a few clicks.

Comment: Have you tried using the booltool addon?

Comment: Hello, I think neither of these topologies is good. The second one is better but both result in N-Gons. You should add the 2 diagonals connected to the 2 corners